# Fatal Error: Class 'CFCredentials' not found - Amazon AWS SDK for S3 error

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have scoured this site as well as Amazon's for solutions, and can't find anything more than user issues which I have resolved.

This error comes up and refers to line 50 of the `config.inc.php` file as follows:

`**Fatal error**:  Class 'CFCredentials' not found in **/home/user/public_html/domain.com/folder/config.inc.php** on line **50**'

Here is line 50 of that file: `CFCredentials::set(array(` followed by 4 required credentials, ie AWS 'key', 'secret', 'default_cache_config', and 'certificate_authority', all of which I have verified and entered correctly.

I'm running the sample file "progress_bar.php" provided by AWS, exactly the way it is without any revisions, and this error keeps showing up.

I have read all the documentation, passed the compatibility test, and pulled out all the remaining hair on my head. Is anyone familiar with the AWS SDK and able to respond with help on this issue?

Comment: CFCredentials is [defined in utilities/credentials.class.php](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#i=CFCredentials).  Does that file exist?  Is it being included?  Could you have some sort of weird frankenstein monster copy of the PHP SDK?  It happens that my local copy is out of date, and that file (and references to CFCredentials) doesn't exist.

Comment: @Charles thank you, yes, credentials.php is in the proper "utilities" folder. I've also installed the latest version 1.5.17.1 of the SDK, downloaded directly from the amazon website.